# Cropping a circle from a matrix in R

Tags: r, image-processing, matrix

I have a large matrix mydata (~2000 X 2000) from which I want to crop some data. I need to get all the values of the cells around a "center cell" in some radius and set all other cells to be 0. Meaning I need to keep the structure of the data and get the values in the circular (defined by a certain radius: r) area around the center center cell (for which I have the coordinated: x_c, y_c). this problem would be similar to cropping a circle from image data.

if I try something like:

> croppedata[x_c-r:x_c+r, y_c-r:y_c+r] = mydata[x_c-r:x_c+r, y_c-r:y_c+r]

I obviously get a rectangle and not a circle... any advise?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Knowledge of geometry is your friend here.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft and probably nested loops too. It could be vectorized instead, but the code would be even more opaque.

Comment: @AllanCameron  Obfuscated code is the best code :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following function will take any square matrix apply a mask to it, such that any cells not within a given radius of the centre are filled with zeros. The remaining cells are left intact. By default, the radius is half the width of the matrix.

```r
circle_mask <- function(m, radius = nrow(m)/2) {
  for(i in seq(nrow(m))) {
    for(j in seq(ncol(m))) {
      r <- sqrt((i - (nrow(m) + 1)/2)^2 + (j - (ncol(m) + 1)/2)^2)
      if(r >= radius) m[i, j] <- 0
    }
  }
  m
}
```

Obviously we don't have your data and can't show a large matrix here in text format, but we can show a simple example to show this on a small scale. Let's start with a 15 x 15 matrix filled with 1s:

```r
m <- matrix(1, 15, 15, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:15], letters[1:15]))

m
#>   a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
#> A 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> C 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> D 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> E 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> F 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> G 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> H 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> I 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> J 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> K 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> L 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> M 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> N 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> O 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Now let's apply a circular mask with a radius of 4 cells:

```r
circle_mask(m, radius = 4)
#>  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
#> A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> E 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> F 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> G 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> H 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> I 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> J 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> K 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> L 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> M 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> N 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

To show larger matrices, we can use `image` to draw a heatmap. Let's create a random 100 x 100 matrix:

```r
mat <- matrix(runif(10000), 100, 100)
image(mat)
```

[image]

Now we see what it looks like with the circle mask applied:

```r
image(circle_mask(mat))
```

[image]

The pale yellow areas are the zero values.

The circle becomes increasingly accurate with larger matrices. Here's a 1000 x 1000 random matrix:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again @Allen Cameron! Made some changes to your code: I've added two arguments, , xc and yc, to set the center cell of the circle, as well as another argument, val, to allow to set any other value to cells outside the circle (e.g., NA). 

circle_mask <- function(m, radius = nrow(m)/2, xc = (nrow(m) + 1)/2, yc = (ncol(m) + 1)/2, val = 0) {
  for(i in seq(nrow(m))) {
    for(j in seq(ncol(m))) {
      r <- sqrt((i - xc)^2 + (j - yc)^2)
      if(r >= radius) m[i, j] <- val
    }
  }
  m
}